# laravel, what are route helpers ( get and post )?

Tags: laravel

I'm upgrading a laravel 5.1 application to laravel 5.2
https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/upgrade#upgrade-5.2.0
in the offical upgrade guide I found this point:

> The get, post, and other route helper functions have been removed. You
>   may use the Route facade instead.

I don't know what are route helper functions, can some help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I show you a route example, with route helper and with route facade

Route Helper

```
<?php 
get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

Route facade

```
<?php
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

For a while, you could write `get()` or `post()` etc. instead of `Route:get()` or `$router->get()` etc. These functions were removed relatively recently. But if you didn't know what they were, then you probably weren't using them. :)